# Default TimeZone with ActiveSupport (without Rails)

Tags: ruby, timezone, activesupport

How does the default TimeZone get set in ActiveSupport?

Here's what's happening:

```
irb -r 'rubygems'
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > require 'active_support' 
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > require 'active_support/time_with_zone'
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > Time.zone
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > nil
```

How do I set that to the current location by default?

Answer (score 8):

in rails it gets set in environment.rb via the rails initializer

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
    config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
    # ...
```

I just did a test and when the config.time_zone is commented out Time.zone will also return nil in the rails project; so I guess there is not a 'default' it just gets set in the initializers

Guessing you already know this will 'work'?

```
irb -r 'rubygems'
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > require 'active_support' 
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > require 'active_support/time_with_zone'
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > Time.zone
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > nil
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > Time.zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > Time.zone
=> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x1215a10 @utc_offset=-28800, @current_period=nil, @name="Pacific Time (US & Canada)", @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: America/Los_Angeles>>
```

Note: above code is using rails 2.2.2 things maybe be different with newer versions?

*editors note*: In rails >= 3.0 all monkey patches have been moved to the `core_ext` namespace, so the above require does not extend `Time`.  For later `ActiveSupport` versions use the following:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/time/zones'
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this outside of rails :)

Comment: I know; what I am saying is that even in rails it doesn't appear to use a default, it seems you will need to set Time.zone yourself in irb? 
but then again maybe I am wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You can set the timezone with values from 2 sources, its own ActiveSupport short list (~137 values, see [ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-c-all) to fetch them) or from the [IANA names](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) (~ 590 values). In this last case you can use the [tzinfo gem](http://tzinfo.rubyforge.org/%22tzinfo%20gem%22) (a dependency of ActiveSupport) to get the list or to instance a [TZInfo::TimezoneProxy](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/frames) :

e.g.

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map &:name

Time.zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.first

Time.zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.first.name

Time.zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"

Time.zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.find_tzinfo "Asia/Tokyo"
```

List all countries, all timezones:

```
TZInfo::Country.all.sort_by { |c| c.name }.each do |c|
  puts c.name # E.g. Norway
  c.zones.each do |z|
    puts "\t#{z.friendly_identifier(true)} (#{z.identifier})" # E.g. Oslo (Europe/Oslo)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like
`Time.zone_default = Time.find_zone! ENV['TZ']`
and set it in an environment variable. Set this in an initializer or environment.rb depending on your project setup.